# gcp google_project_iam_member gives invalid argument message on terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm using terraform to deploy the following

```
resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "brw-user-function-item-registered-role" {
  role_id     = "brw_user_function_item_registered_role"
  title       = "brw-user-function-item-registered-role"
  description = "Role used by the brw-user-function item-registered"
  permissions = [     
    "storage.objects.create",
    "storage.objects.get",
    "storage.objects.list"
  ]
}

resource "google_service_account" "brw-user-function-item-registered-service-account" {
  account_id   = "brw-user-function-item-reg-svc"
  display_name = "brw-user-function-item-registered-service_account"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "brw-user-function-item-registered-service-account-binding" {  
  project = local.project
  role    = "roles/${google_project_iam_custom_role.brw-user-function-item-registered-role.role_id}"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.brw-user-function-item-registered-service-account.email}"
  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_custom_role.brw-user-function-item-registered-role,
    google_service_account.brw-user-function-item-registered-service-account
  ]
}
```

However when I try to deploy this through terraform, I get the following error

```
Request "Create IAM Members roles/brw_user_function_item_registered_role serviceAccount:brw-user-function-item-reg-svc@brw-user.iam.gserviceaccount.com for \"project \\\"BRW-User\\\"\"" returned error: Error retrieving IAM policy for project "BRW-User": googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here, I have added the `depends_on` as well just to make sure it is created in the correct order.  Could the `member` attribute be wrong, I tried giving `account_id` as well and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only predefined roles have the string **roles/** in front of the name.

You are using the string:

```
role = "roles/${google_project_iam_custom_role.brw-user-function-item-registered-role.role_id}"
```

Change it to:

```
role = google_project_iam_custom_role.brw-user-function-item-registered-role.name
```

Note the removal of **roles/**, changing **role_id** to **name**, and removing string interpolation.

Comment: John, I thought custom roles must be passed as [projects|organizations]/{parent-name}/roles/{role-name} per the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#argument-reference

Comment: @CaioT - They must follow the format. Both your answer (with a minor mistake) and my answer generate the same value using the format in your answer. My answer uses the built-in features of Terraform and your answer hand creates the role name value. Your mistake is the **customer_access** part which is probably from your test HCL. Note the difference between **role_id** which generates the short name and **name** which generates the long name. If a terraform beginner studies both of our answers they will learn more about how values are created.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the resource google_project_iam_member, if you are passing a custom role it must be of the format:

```
[projects|organizations]/{parent-name}/roles/{role-name}
```

Here is an example:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "access" {
  project = var.project_name
  role    = "projects/${var.project_name}/roles/${google_project_iam_custom_role.customer_access.role_id}"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}
```

Also, as a best practice avoid using dashes in the resources name (better underscore) and try not make it too long. I've run into issues with long names.